# How to realize custom exception handler using Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, exception, spring-webflux

A have next classes:

SaleRouter.java

```
@Configuration
public class SaleRouter {

@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(@Value("${server.servlet.context-path}") String contextPath,
                                            SaleHandler saleHandler) {
    return RouterFunctions.route().path(contextPath, mainPath -> mainPath.path("/sale", funcPath -> funcPath
            .POST(saleHandler::postSale)))
            .DELETE(saleHandler::deleteSale).filter(validate()).build();
}

private static HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> validate() {
    return (serverRequest, handlerFunction) -> {
        Optional<String> email = serverRequest.queryParam("email");
        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Error in input param: email - null");
        } else if (!EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email.get())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Error in input param: email - " + email.get());
        }
        return handlerFunction.handle(serverRequest);
    };
}
}
```

SaleHandler.java

```
@Component
public class SaleHandler {
public Mono<ServerResponse> postSale(ServerRequest request) {
    return ok().build();
}

public Mono<ServerResponse> deleteSale(ServerRequest request) {
    return ok().build();
}
}
```

RestExceptionHandler.java

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
@Slf4j
public class RestExceptionHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {

@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, Throwable throwable) {
    serverWebExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    if (throwable instanceof BadRequestException) {
        serverWebExchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail("BadRequest", throwable.getMessage());
        return serverWebExchange.getResponse()
                .writeWith(new Jackson2JsonEncoder()
                        .encode(Mono.just(errorDetail), serverWebExchange.getResponse().bufferFactory(),
                                ResolvableType.forInstance(errorDetail), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                                Hints.from(Hints.LOG_PREFIX_HINT, serverWebExchange.getLogPrefix())));
    }
    return Mono.empty();
}
}
```

BadRequestException.class

```
@Getter
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
private final String message;

public BadRequestException(String message){
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

ErrorDetails.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ErrorDetail {
    private final String serviceName = "app";
    private String errorCode;
    private String userMessage;
}
```

SaleRouterTests.java

```
class SaleRouterTests {

private static final String EMAIL = "email";
private static final String EMAIL_VALUE = "test@gmail.com";

private static final String SALE_PATH = "/sale";
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "app";
private static final String BAD_REQUEST = "BadRequest";

private static final RouterFunction<ServerResponse> saleRouterFunc =
        new SaleRouter().route("", new SaleHandler());

private final WebTestClient webTestClient;

public SaleRouterTests() {
    webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(saleRouterFunc).build();
}

@Test
void givenSaleRouter_WhenSalePostWithValidQueryParams_ThenOk() {
    webTestClient.post()
            .uri(uriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(SALE_PATH)
                            .queryParam(EMAIL, EMAIL_VALUE)
                            .build())
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
}

@Test
void givenSaleRouter_WhenSalePostWithoutEmailQueryParam_ThenBadRequest() {
    webTestClient.post()
            .uri(uriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(SALE_PATH)
                            .build())
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
            .expectBody(ErrorDetail.class)
            .value(response -> {
                Assertions.assertEquals("Error in input param: email - null", response.getUserMessage());
                    });
    }
  }
}
```

I want validate query params and return error response using calling exception if param email in null.
But this doesn't work.

Output from test class:

```
com.pack.exception.BadRequestException: Error in input param: email - null
at com.pack.controller.SaleRouter.lambda$validate$2(SaleRouter.java:40)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/sale" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
    at com.pack.controller.SaleRouter.lambda$validate$2(SaleRouter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$apply$2(HandlerFilterFunction.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions$RouterFunctionWebHandler.lambda$null$1(RouterFunctions.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions$RouterFunctionWebHandler.wrapException(RouterFunctions.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions$RouterFunctionWebHandler.lambda$null$2(RouterFunctions.java:1253)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281)

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400 BAD_REQUEST> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>

> POST /sale
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]

No content

< 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR Internal Server Error
< 

0 bytes of content (unknown content-type).
```

tell me please how to do it correctly and where my mistake?
There is a suspicion that RestExceptionHandler does not work, but why?

Comment: well the purpose with functional endpoints is to not have exceptionhandlers. By using functional endpoints you have made a low level choice to sort of handle the exceptions yourself. But you have some options, like for instance overriding the `ErrorAttributes` bean if you want a custom body, but otherwise you should return your own custom Responses in the routerHandler as stated in this github issue  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12414

Comment: @AlexZhur I think your custom error handler works fine if you run it. But when testing this, custom error handler is not picked up in the test.

Comment: @NipunaSaranga yes, he really works. But how can I use this handler in unit tests ?